# Repeated measures logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, repeated-measures, contrasts

I have a dataset that features a binary outcome, a binary predictor, and an unordered factor with 7 levels, and 120 subjects. Each of the 120 subjects were asked a binary question on seven issues, hence the 7-level unordered factor. Therefore, I have a total of 840 observations. Each of the 840 observations has a binary predictor, and a binary outcome. I want to regress the binary outcome, on the binary predictor of course.

The outcome is slightly complicated. I will use mac vs. PCs as an example. People are asked, "Do you think macs are better or do you think PCs are better?" That is recorded as a 1, for preferring macs, and 0 for preferring PCs. Then they are asked "Is your opinion based on objective truth, or subjective opinion?" In other words, do you think it is objective (1) or subjective (0). Then the last question is "In 20 years, will people think macs are better or will people think PCs are better?" Again, 1 will be coded for macs. A new variable is then created. The variable is 1 if their current opinion matches what they think the future opinion will be. Previous pilot studies found that people tend to believe their stance on issues is what the future will be (...I know, a pretty intuitive finding...people tend to think they are right). The outcome is that variable, whether their current opinion agrees with what they think the future will be. So the point is to see if how people view things as subjective vs. objective, predicts whether they think their vision of the future is in line with their beliefs. The mac vs PC is only an example of an issue. In reality, there are seven issues, ranging from gun control, to abortion, etc., and each of those seven issue ranges in "objectivity" given by how the participants answered the objectivity question.

- `Participant ID`: 120 Factors
- `Objectivity`: Binary predictor of 0s and 1s
- `Outcome`: Binary outcome of 0s and 1s
- `Issue`: 7-factor level variable

So I tried something like this:

```
  # Dummy coding for all participants
contrasts(data$Participant) <- contr.treatment(120)  #$
  # Deviance coding to compare to the overall mean
contrasts(data$Issue)       <- contr.sum(7) 
model <- glmer(Outcome ~ Objectivity*Issue + (Objectivity*Issue|Participant), 
               family=binomial, data=data)
```

This gives a bunch of warnings. I essentially want to see if my predictor predicts the outcome, based on the seven issue, while adding a random effect for the participant ID.

Comment: Are you thinking of the 7 issues as related? Do you think they all measure some underlying latent variable?

Comment: They are related in the sense that each of the seven issues vary in objectivity. The issues range from preference of soda (the least objective), and issues such as gun control (people view more as objective). So the whole point is to see whether the issue, which each participant has voted on as either subjective or objective, is predictive of my outcome.

Comment: What then is your outcome? I thought the yes or no for each of the 7 questions was your outcome.

Comment: I will update the posting because I don't have enough characters to explain.

Comment: Based on your update, it isn't clear how you would have 7 responses for each person. It seems like you should have just 1, in which case you could use ordinary logistic regression instead of GLiMeM (ie `glm()` rather than `glmer()`).

Comment: I have seven because each person answered those sets of questions for each of the seven issues. So one unit, answered the objectivity question, as well as the current opinion and the 20 years later question, seven times for each issue.